# WOW.js with Pure CSS parallax scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I have used this [Pure CSS Parallax Websites](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) tutorial for creating my parallax site and it works great!

However, when used in combination with WOW.js, none of the animations are triggered on scroll, no matter what. I think there is some sort of confusion in the programs as to what the actual scroll height of the browser must be if there are many parallax layers there.

So, is there any way I can get viewport-triggered animations to work with a pure CSS parallax effect?

Comment: Putting the animation data attributes on ANY of the elements in the Group of the Parallax (#group1, .title, parallax-layer__base etc.) doesn't trigger the animation at all.

Comment: Hi @xdragonforce I'm now having this exact same problem.  Did you find a fix at all?